# What is the Rust equivalent to C++'s virtual functions?

Tags: oop, rust, traits

I'm trying to implement something in Rust that works like a C++ virtual function in a class, I would have a base struct with data, then I would keep some functions undefined, like the following example:

```cpp
class A {
    int stuff;
public:
    virtual void foo(int a, int b) = 0;
    void function_that_calls_foo() { /*...*/ foo(1, 2); /*...*/ }
}

class B: public A { void foo(int a, int b) { /* ... */ } }
```

I was trying to implement it using function pointers, but without much success. I could use a trait with A's functions, and implement A on the other class, but I would lose the struct's data. What's the best (fastest?) way to implement this kind of thing in Rust?

```
struct A {
    ...
}

impl A {
    fn function_that_calls_foo(&self) {
        ...
        self.foo(a, b);
        ...
    }
}

struct B {
    a: A;
}

impl B {
    fn xxx(&self) {
        a.function_that_calls_foo(1, 2);
    }

    fn foo(&self, a: i32, b: i32) {...}
}
```

Comment: You're looking for [trait objects](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch17-02-trait-objects.html).

Comment: So, Rust is very much *Composition Over Inheritance*.

Comment: These kinds of questions, "How do I do class inheritance in Rust?" are usually solved best by taking a step back, looking at the actual problem you're trying to solve (the *real* problem, not a fake problem with `foo` and `xxx` for function names) and looking at your new toolbox. If you try to translate class inheritance directly into Rust code, you'll figure out a way to make it work, but the code may be very clunky compared to more idiomatic Rust code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> keep some functions undefined

I'm adding the implicit "and have some functions that call that to-be-defined function".

As [E_net4 says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44783925/what-is-the-rust-equivalent-to-cs-virtual-functions#comment76548783_44783925), use a [*trait*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/second-edition/ch10-02-traits.html):

```
trait Foo {
    fn foo(&self, a: i32, b: i32) -> i32;

    fn function_that_calls_foo(&self) {
        println!("{}", self.foo(1, 2));
    }
}
```

You can then implement the trait for `Base`:

```
struct Base {
    stuff: i32,
}

impl Foo for Base {
    fn foo(&self, a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 {
        self.stuff + a + b
    }
}
```

And as [Matthieu M. says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44783925/what-is-the-rust-equivalent-to-cs-virtual-functions#comment76550136_44783925), Rust doesn't have inheritance, so use composition:

```
struct Base {
    stuff: i32,
}

impl Base {
    fn reusable(&self) -> i32 {
        self.stuff + 1
    }
}

struct Alpha {
    base: Base,
    modifier: i32,
}

impl Foo for Alpha {
    fn foo(&self, a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 {
        (self.base.reusable() + a + b) * self.modifier
    }
}
```

You can combine the two concepts as well, by taking a [*generic*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/second-edition/ch10-00-generics.html) that is constrained by a type parameter.

---

I'll strongly second [Dietrich Epp's point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44783925/what-is-the-rust-equivalent-to-cs-virtual-functions/44786419#comment76553471_44783925). Using a new  language should involve checking out new paradigms. Inheritance for the purposes of code reuse is not usually a great idea, even in languages that support it. Instead, create smaller building blocks and combine them together.

Comment: The most important part of your answer is this: "Using a new language should involve checking out new paradigms", in my opinion. Too often forgotten.

Comment: "Inheritnace for the purposes of code reuse" - Why is it not a good idea? Isn't it one of the main points in OOP?

Comment: @YuriFeldman the question is about C++ _virtual_ functions, which have no code to reuse.

Comment: @Shepmaster Only if you define "code" as the _body_ of a function. I feel that "interfaces" (in the C++ sense, not the Java sense) also count as "code" insofar as adding them to a type still constitutes a lot of tedium for the programmer (when you consider line-of-business software where a type may have dozens of members). At least Rust has traits/mixins, but this isn't a perfect solution.

Comment: Not using inheritance for code reuse is not Rust-specific at all and can be applied in C++ just as well (and is even encouraged by many guidelines). You can have pure interfaces in C++, and you also have compile-time polymorphism in the form of templates. Granted, it's all a bit hairy, but it is there, and there's no "new paradigm" or something involved.