# What does 'Zero Cost Abstraction' mean?

Tags: rust

I came across this term when exploring Rust.

I saw different kinds of explanations regarding this and still don't quite get the ideas.

In *The Embedded Rust Book*, it said

> Type states are also an excellent example of Zero Cost Abstractions
>
> - the ability to move certain behaviors to compile time execution or analysis.
>
> These type states contain no actual data, and are instead used as
> markers.
>
> Since they contain no data, they have no actual representation in
> memory at runtime:

Does it mean the runtime is faster because there is no memory in runtime?

Appreciate it if anyone can explain it in an easy to understand way.

Comment: Zero Cost Abstractions don't make anything faster, rather they (hopefully) make the runtime *exactly the same* as if you wrote the lower level unabstracted version (usually at the expense of compile time). The idea is generally adding a convenience abstraction layer, but without incurring any runtime penalties.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Zero Cost Abstractions means adding higher-level programming concepts, like generics, collections and so on do not come with a run-time cost, only compile time cost (the code will be slower to compile). Any operation on zero-cost abstractions is as fast as you would write out matching functionality by hand using lower-level programming concepts like for loops, counters, ifs and using raw pointers.

Or another way to view this is that using zero-cost abstraction tools, functions, templates, classes and such come with "zero cost" for the performance of your code.

Answer (score 19):

Zero cost abstractions are ones that bear no runtime costs in execution speed or memory usage.

By contrast, virtual methods are a good example of a *costly* abstraction: in many OO languages the type of the method's caller is determined at runtime which requires maintaining a lookup table (runtime memory usage) and then actually performing the lookup (runtime overhead per method call, likely at least an extra pointer dereference) with the runtime type to determine which version of the method to call. Another good example would be garbage collection: in return for being able to not worry about the details of memory allocation you pay with GC pauses.

Rust though mostly tries to have zero cost abstractions: ones that let you have your cake and eat it too. Ones that compiler can safely and correctly convert to forms that bear no extra indirection/memory usage. In fact, the only thing that I'm aware of (somebody more knowledgeable correct me if I'm wrong) that you really pay for at runtime in Rust is bounds checking and `dyn` (see the bit about virtual methods above).

Comment: Rust has traits which provide runtime virtual function behaviour, for one (see e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44786419/256138))

Comment: @rubenvb I didn't realize those were dispatched at runtime, I thought the receiver's type had to be known at compile time.

Comment: Well, it seems Rust is "smart" in the sense that it will "devirtualize" trait usage when possible (at least that's how I read [this blog post](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2015/05/11/traits.html) with my C++ glasses). I think it comes down to Rust providing unified syntax for static and dynamic dispatching.

Comment: Traits may be dispatched at runtime or compile time. If you have a `struct Foo: Bar` and a variable `let foo = Foo{}` then calling a method from `Bar` will be dispatched at compile-time (zero-cost). However if your variable is a `Bar` reference: `let bar = &foo as &Bar`, then dispatching will be done at runtime using the same kind of lookup table as most OO languages (unless the optimizer is able to go back to the `Foo` type, which some OO languages can do too).

Comment: @Jmb Rust only uses dynamic dyspatch when you use `dyn`, as in `&dyn Trait`. Otherwise it always uses compile-time dispatch, even for references.

Comment: @Dev no, if `Bar` is a trait, then `&Bar` is just a deprecated way of writing `&dyn Bar` and they behave exactly the same way → dynamic dispatch unless the compiler is able to know the actual type of the variable (e.g. because it's a local variable anyway) and optimize it to a static call.

Comment: @Jmb Omitting `dyn` is a hard error in newer editions. Even when it wasn't, `&Bar` is just syntax sugar for `&dyn Bar` - it only uses dynamic dispatch because it is a *trait object*. For more information on trait objects, which is the *only* scenario in which rustc uses dynamic dispatch (vtables), see: https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/trait-object.html

Comment: @Dev so basically you're saying that my original comment was right?

Comment: @Jmb Your original comment was quite fuzzy, and specified something about trait references being dispatched at compile time if the "optimizer is able to go back to the `Foo` type". However, references to trait objects are *always* dispatched at runtime using a vtable, there is no "if" about it, and things that are not trait objects are *always* dispatched at compile-time, again there is no "if" about it. "dyn" is *the* marker of runtime dispatch.

Comment: @Dev if you look at the assembly for [this playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=8f6f578ae4a123d836acfea28ca19925), you will notice that the call to `bar.bar()` is actually _inlined_ without using the `&dyn Bar` vtable because the compiler was smart enough to recognize that `bar` always refers to a `Foo` instance even though it's a trait object.

Comment: @Jmb I believe that's because the reference was eliminated completely, which also eliminated the vtable.

Comment: @Jmb If you prevent the optimizer from removing the reference completely, [you get a vtable](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=cb249240516553046c17c319eff97497), even though the only struct in the entire world that implements `Bar` is `Foo`.

Comment: @Dev I'm not sure what your point is. The whole idea behind `black_box` is to prevent this kind of optimization, so of course if you use `black_box` the compiler is no longer able to see that `bar` refers to a `Foo` instance and has to use dynamic dispatch.

Comment: @Jmb My point is that `&dyn` references do not magically perform compile-time dispatch when the compiler feels like. The reason why simple cases can omit the vtable is because the `&dyn` reference gets completely optimized out. Therefore my point still stands that `&dyn` is always dynamic dispatch and everything else is always compile-time dispatch. Sometimes the `&dyn` is optimized out, like pretty much anything else you can do in Rust.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245169/discussion-between-dev-and-jmb).

Answer (score 7):

The concept of zero cost abstractions originally came from the functional world. However, the terminology comes from C++. According to Bjarne Stroustrup,

> In general, C++ implementations obey the
> zero-overhead principle: What you don’t use, you don’t pay for. And further: What you do use, you couldn’t hand code any better.

This quote along with most answers fail to deliver the idea in its entirety because the context in which these were said isn't explicitly stated.

If there was only one programming language in the world: be it Rust or C++, zero-cost abstractions would be indistinguishable from most other compiler optimizations. The implication here is that there are countless other languages that let you do the same things as Rust or C++, but with a nonzero and often runtime-specific cost.

Comment: Do you have a reference supporting that this originates from functional programming?

Comment: @mkrieger1 no need for references, it's clear that functional programming, which is a style of programming that emphasizes the use of pure functions, immutable data, and declarative constructs to create programs that are easy to reason about and maintain, are the perfect example Zero-cost abstraction.

Comment: @JulianoSilva depends on what you are comparing the abstraction to. Immutable data means that you will do a copy-on-write instead of inplace operation (hence why games and matrix computing is expensive in FP). It also requires GC (or some other automated memory management) to clean up unused data (although technically, Haskell's gc "saves used data" instead of "collecting garbage")

Comment: @gust you are correct, let me fix my comment: zero-cost abstraction is not particular from functional paradigms, which often requires memoizing data in order to be eficient, as opposite: it is how entities with data and behavior together are used in higher levels implementation that makes zero-cost abstractions useful, such as OOP, Metaprogramming and Generics Programming

Answer (score -2):

Zero-cost abstraction refers to the concept of using abstractions in code that are both expressive and efficient, without incurring any additional runtime overhead. This concept is particularly associated with the C++ programming language, which was one of the first languages to pioneer metaprogramming, generic programming, and object-oriented programming, all of which can be used to achieve zero-cost abstractions.

On the other hand we have functional programming, while it can also make use of abstractions, is not typically associated with zero-cost abstraction, as its emphasis on immutability can require additional memory allocation and copy-on-write operations (following gust comment), which can impact performance in certain use cases, such as real-time game programming or matrix computing.

Comment: Please delete you answer chatGPT answers are not allowed

Comment: @AhmedSbai what makes you think of that? I crafted this based on the previous knowledge in this post

Comment: Bro it is the same answer that chatGPT gives

Comment: it may be identical for sure, it's because I use it a lot and my language may be mimicking it, but this doesn't necessarily mean that I literally copied, it's based on my knowledge, the concept of difference of in place operation vs copy-on-write was good to make it known in a good answer for this question.

Comment: AI detector thinks this is a real text, not AI-generated. *But*, you say "I use it a lot and my language may be mimicking it" and here's a friendly tip: you should not do that. It will only cause you issues. And this is not a good style to copy anyway. If you imitate GPT's style you will likely have problems in the future.

Comment: @EricAya that's a very good point, I find myself going into some inertial direction to where language can be thought as I move more and more into a technical language, as my native language is another the way I learnt to present logical information is quite the way logical information could best be presented itself, somehow similar to what artificial general intelligence would look like, because I literally act like if it has no limits to my perceptions input, therefore, I do not indict anyone who complains about, is the way I best choice to make use of words sometimes.

Comment: The notion of a zero-cost abstraction makes no promises around expressiveness - and the way you phrase this is at its base misleading as a result. The whole reason to use an abstraction is expressiveness, the zero-cost part is saying that this expressiveness should not be traded off with runtime costs ('efficiency' if you're being sloppy with terms). To go on to suggest that functional languages, which are often operating over functions rather than over data, are somehow are more prone to non-zero-cost abstractions is a shaky assertion at best, and not true in practice.