# Java to Solidity translator: is there a possibility to write smart contracts in Java?

Tags: java, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, code-translation

Is there a tool out there that can automatically convert Java to Solidity? And can we convert Java file to Solidity？

I found that there exists Jthereum that is in its beta version now. Is there a simpler and/or more robust tool to write smart contracts in Java or to translate Java code into Solidity code?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there isn't a way. Only thing I heard of is that cardano is working on a thing called IELE that will eventually be able to translate languages like c++ and java to smart contract code however in their case it will be to haskell not to solidity.

Comment: I found that Corda supports writing smart contracts in Java, please check https://github.com/corda/corda.

Answer (score -2):

> Is there a tool out there that can automatically convert Java to Solidity? And can we convert Java file to Solidity？

In theory, you can even write smart contracts in [Brainfuck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck). While both Solidity and Java are Turing complete languages, any such converted would not be meaningful.

- There is no point to write smart contracts in Java, because it is not about the language, it is about the exotic runtime that EVM offers
- Solidity is easy language to learn
- Java is a bad language for writing smart contracts
- [Smart contract programming is not difficult due to programming language, but due to difficult and adverse run-time environment](https://twitter.com/moo9000/status/1344610584864677890)
- Users of such tools cannot easily access or understand open source golden standard smart contracts like OpenZeppelin
- EVM smart contracts need to be heavily hand optimised and any translator is unlikely to have [zero abstraction cost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69178380/what-does-zero-cost-abstraction-mean)

While it is a theory in possible, the idea of translator works very badly in the context of smart contracts.